# Can I set different degrees of parallelism for different targets with the R {targets} package?

Tags: r, r-future, targets-r-package

I'm testing out the `targets` package and am running into a problem with customizing parallelization. My workflow has two steps, and I'd like to parallelize the first step over 4 workers and the second step over 16 workers.

I want to know if I can solve the problem by calling `tar_make_future()`, and then specifying how many workers each step requires in the `tar_target` calls. I've got a simple example below, where I'd like the `data` step to execute with 1 worker, and the `sums` step to execute with 3 workers.

```
library(targets)

tar_dir({
  tar_script({
    library(future)
    library(future.callr)
    library(dplyr)

    plan(callr)

    list(
      # Goal: this step should execute with 1 worker
      tar_target(
        data,
        data.frame(
          x = seq_len(6),
          id = rep(letters[seq_len(3)], each = 2)
        ) %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          tar_group(),
        iteration = "group"
      ),
      # Goal: this step should execute with 3 workers, in parallel
      tar_target(
        sums,
        sum(data$x),
        pattern = map(data),
        iteration = "vector"
      )
    )
  })
  tar_make_future()
})
```

I know that one option is to configure the parallel backend separately within each step, and then call `tar_make()` to execute the workflow serially. I'm curious about whether I can get this kind of result with `tar_make_future()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you call `tar_make_future(workers = <max_parallel_workers>)` and let `targets` figure out how many workers to run in parallel. `targets` automatically figures out which targets can run in parallel and which need to wait for upstream dependencies to finish. In your case, some of the `data` branches may finish before others, in which case `sum` can start right away. In other words, some `sum` branches will start running before other `sum` branches can start, and you can trust `targets` to scale up transient workers when the need arises. The animation at https://books.ropensci.org/targets/hpc.html#future may help visualize this. If you were to micromanage the parallelism for `data` and `sum` separately, you would likely have to wait for all of `data` to finish before any of `sum` can start, which could take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for my case was to call `tar_make_future()` twice. In the example above, that would be:

```
tar_make_future(data, workers = 1)
tar_make_future(workers = 3)
```

Though in my actual workflow it looks more like:

```
tar_make_future(data, workers = 4)
tar_make_future(workers = <max_parallel_workers>)
```

@landau raises a good point that this completely builds the `data` target before moving on to subsequent steps. There are certainly workflows where a clean and effective solution is to call `tar_make_future(workers = <max_parallel_workers>)` and accept the resulting runtime.

In my case, waiting for `data` to finish wasn't an issue: my `data` target contained many branches that were fast, subsequent targets were much slower to build, and I could parallelize the slow step over many more workers than the fast step (16+ workers for the slow step, vs. just 4 for the fast step). If these aren't true of your situation, @landau's suggestion may be a better solution.